# Verify text that has symbols

Tags: ruby, regex, watir

I need to verify text shows up on a webpage. 
Some of the text has symbols.

What is the best way to validate that the following appears on my page

```
"Test® Software for the low price of 7.451¢ per install"
```

I've looked at trying to escape the symbols but Im getting the following errors

```
 test.rb:61: invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII)
 test.rb:61: unterminated string meets end of file
 test.rb:61: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting keyword_then or ';' or '\n'
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to put

```
# encoding: UTF-8
```

at the top of the test file containing the unicode characters. This is known as a "magic comment". You can and should read more about [encoding in Ruby 1.9](http://blog.grayproductions.net/articles/ruby_19s_three_default_encodings).

Comment: i dont get the error. But now when I try to find the text it seems to not find it.

    if
    browser.text.include? 'Test® Software for the low price      7.451¢ per install'
    puts "pass"
    else
    "fail"
    end

It will not return anything

Comment: Does your test pass if you remove the unicode symbols from the view and test? Also, why are you `puts`ing pass/fail instead of using assertions?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to use HTML entities instead of symbols for display. If you do that, you can check for those entities in your test without these problems. So the HTML becomes:

```
"Test&#174; Software for the low price of 7.451&#162; per install"
```